# Uncaught ReferenceError: total cost is not defined

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I've looked over and over it, but I can't seem to find the problem. When I load the script in Google Chrome's JavaScript console, it returns the following error back to me
`Uncaught referenceerror: total cost is not defined`. This happens by the `document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML` code.

I've tried to split up the formula, give it another name, recombined the formula, but it still gives me the same error.

```
//waarde vasthouden
  function calcul(){
    var fund = parseFloat(document.getElementById("fund").value);
    var age1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("age1").value);
    var age2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("age2").value);
    var age3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("age3").value);
    var age4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("age4").value);
    var age5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("age5").value);
    var age6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("age6").value);
    var primcost = parseFloat(document.getElementById("primcost").value);
    var seccost = parseFloat(document.getElementById("seccost").value);
    var unicost = parseFloat(document.getElementById("unicost").value);
    var start = parseFloat(document.getElementById("start").value);
    var annrate = parseFloat(document.getElementById("annrate").value);
    //additional calculations
    //Duration primary school
    var primdur = (age2 - age1) + 1; 
    //Present Value Primary School before starting
    var pvprim = primcost * ((1 - (Math.pow((1 + (annrate / 100)), primdur))) / (annrate / 100));
    //Duration secondary school
    var secdur = (age4 - age3) + 1; 
    //Present Value secondary School before starting
    var pvsec = seccost * ((1 - (Math.pow((1 + (annrate / 100)), secdur))) / (annrate / 100));
    //Duration university
    var unidur = (age6 - age5) + 1; 
    //Present Value university before starting
    var pvuni = unicost * ((1 - (Math.pow((1 + (annrate / 100)), unidur))) / (annrate / 100));
    //Present value when starting primary school
    //var X1 = ((pvprim) / (Math.pow((1 + (annrate / 100)), (age1 - 1))));
    //Present value when starting secondary school
    //var X2 = ((pvsec) / (Math.pow((1 + (annrate / 100)), (age3 - 1))));
    //Present value when starting university
    //var X3 = ((pvuni) / (Math.pow((1 + (annrate / 100)), (age5 - 1))));
    //Annual deposits (PV formula)
    var totalcost = ((pvprim) / (Math.pow((1 + (annrate / 100)), (age1 - 1)))) + 
    ((pvsec) / (Math.pow((1 + (annrate / 100)), (age3 - 1)))) + 
    ((pvuni) / (Math.pow((1 + (annrate / 100)), (age5 - 1))));
    var othcalc = (1 / (annrate / 100)) - ((1 / ((annrate / 100)*(Math.pow((1 + (annrate / 100)), age5)))));
  }

//binnen in script resterende decimal code, nadat alle variabelen zijn gedefinieerd
        var decs = +(document.getElementById('dec').value);
        calculated = true; //end of decimal code

//Eindantwoord weergeven in decimalen
 document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =(((totalcost) - fund) / othcalc).toFixed(decs);
</script>
```

Is this because my `var totalcost` is incorrect, or is this because of another mistake? The built in Google Sites HTML-box doesn't give me any errors, but the JSconsole does.

Comment: I don't understand it. In all my other templates and files, it worked.  Here is an example where it worked: http://jsfiddle.net/VapTM/

Answer (score 0):

All the variables you are wrapping inside the function `calcul` are inside a distinct scope, so they are only available inside this function. In JavaScript you are defining a new scope when you are starting a new function.

You will either have to set the `innerHTML` inside the `calcul`-function or to return the values that you need to do that in some way (i.e. by returning a JavaScript-object).

The second problem you have, is that you are not calling the function before you are trying to use the values you are calculating inside.

Try the following

```
function calcul() {
  // Your calculation logic goes here
  return { "fund": fund, "totalcost": totalcost, "othcalc": othcalc };
}

var decs = +(document.getElementById('dec').value);
var results = calcul();
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML =(((results.totalcost) - results.fund) / results.othcalc).toFixed(decs);
```

Comment: Because the innerHTML is set directly after the calulation, i.e. in the same function, so in the same scope and so the variables still hold the used values. In your case, the innerHTML is not set in the function where the calculation is done.

Comment: Another way to make your function work is to put the last 3 commands _inside_ the `calcul`-function. That is what you are doing in this fiddle. This would fix your problem, but I think it is no good approach, because you are doing hard when you would like to reuse the function for another task, where you would not like to set the innerHTML of `answer`.

Answer (score 0):

Define `totalcost` as global variable so you can access `totalcost` value outside of function.

```
var totalcost; // define this var outside of function calcul()
```

In your

```
function calcul() {

       // here replace `var totalcost` with `totalcost`

}
```

Comment: Tried it, but I still get the error. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K75Uy/

Or I've entered it wrong, that is also possible

Comment: @user2686401 Check my edit. remove var from totalcost inside function. and define var totalcost outside of function.

Comment: Found the solution. I've just closed the `function ()` too early. Added a `}` after `document.get......` and now, it works at least. There is still a mistake in the formula, but that's something I have to sort it out by myself. Everyone thanks!

Comment: @user2686401 , if you found solution its really great .... no need for thanks bro..